# Can java main class parameters be changed?

Tags: java, parameters, program-entry-point, nosuchmethoderror

The usual parameter is (String[] arg). This i take a parameter that take a string array. When i change this to (Int arg) i get a run time error "no such method error". I know the error is caused by changing the parameter.
My question is can I change the parameter form a String array to something else or can you only use the preset parameter?

Answer (score 6):

In short, no.  If you want to reference a single integer argument, use

`int number = Integer.parseInt(arg[0])`

Of course, you'll want to use some exception handling, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is a list of the command-line arguments, which are passed by the shell to your program as strings.  It wouldn't make sense to change it from `String []`.  But you're free to parse the strings in whatever manner is appropriate for your program.